# Annotation Processor - How to get the Class it is processing

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, java-compiler-api

I am trying to write a custom Anntoation processor.
The annotation processor will process each class file at compile time to check annotations,
But how am i able to get the class that it is currently processing?
I am only able to get the class name in the following codes.

```
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
  ......
    @Override
     public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

     Set<? extends Element> rootE=roundEnv.getRootElements();
       for(Element e: rootE) {
        if(e.getKind()==ElementKind.CLASS) {
            String className= e.getSimpleName().toString();
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage( javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING,className, e); 
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are unable to access the Class the Annotation Processor is processing because the Class has not been compiled yet.  Instead Java offers the analogous Elements api for reflection-style inspection of the input source.

The Element (which you found by using `roundEnv.getRootElements()`) has much more information about the class being compiled than just its name.  A ton of useful information can be found by using the ElementVisitors:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/ElementVisitor.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/ElementKindVisitor6.html

Including the classes constructor, methods, fields, etc.

Here's how to use it:

```
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
......
    @Override
     public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

         Set<? extends Element> rootE=roundEnv.getRootElements();
         for(Element e: rootE) {
             for(Element subElement : e.getEnclosedElements()){
                 subElement.accept(new ExampleVisitor(), null); // implement ExampleVisitor
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "... has much more information about the class being compiled than just its name", but how _do_ you get the class name?

Comment: The class name will be in the Element.getSimpleName() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getSimpleName%28%29

Answer (score 14):

1. This **is NOT** how AnnotationProcessing works. You cannot get a `Class<?>` object during processing becuase the classes that you want definition of **are being compiled right NOW**!
   If you call `getClass()` on an unknown class or use `Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.your.fancy.Class")` you'll get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` which is completely fine.
2. You need to use classes such as `javax.lang.model.element.Element` and `javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement` to describe/read your class definitions.
3. The `javax.lang.model.*` has **`javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror`** to describe classes, their fields, methods etc.
4. If you need more insight, just include **tools.jar** from the java compiler (JAVA SDK) to get more type definitions which are used during compilation. But most probably - you **DON'T need** to add this jar dependency!
5. You'll get `ClassNotFoundException` even after `roundEnvironment.processingOver()` is **true**.
6. **IN SHORT: USE  TypeMirror in all the places where you wanted to use the Class type**.

**Examples:**

- get list of methods from a class:

```
public static @Nonnull List getMethods(@Nonnull Element annotationElem, @Nonnull RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
    List outList = new ArrayList();

    String simpleName = annotationElem.getSimpleName().toString();
    for (Element elem  : roundEnvironment.getRootElements())
        if (elem.getSimpleName().toString().equals(simpleName))
            for (Element methodDeclaration :elem.getEnclosedElements())
                if (methodDeclaration instanceof ExecutableElement)
                    outList.add((ExecutableElement)methodDeclaration);

    return outList;
}
```

- get method name from method declaration:

```
public static TypeMirror getMethodFirstParam(@Nonnull ExecutableElement method, int n) {
     List parameters = ((ExecutableElement) method).getParameters();
     if (parameters != null && parameters.size() > 0)
         return parameters.get(n).asType();
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Is the annotationElem a root element of the roundEnvironment?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you can use: `subElement.getEnclosingElement()` so you can get parent element which may be the class element as you want.